# How <iframe src can read local temp file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How I can save file in web server folder's instead of local client's folder ?.
Or how I can move a file from local client's folder to web server's folder ?

My problem, is that I would like to read a file in local using src , and as you know src only for web server's files.

Here is my code .aspx:

```
<IFRAME id=iframePDF style="WIDTH: 720px; HEIGHT: 700px" runat="server"></IFRAME>
```

Here is Code-Behind :

```
    sFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() 
    System.IO.File.Move(sFilePath, System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf"))
    sFilePath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf")
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sFilePath, buffer)
    iframePDF.Attributes.Add("src", sFilePath)
```

The problem is:
sFilePath is a local path , and src can not read local path ?

Thanks for your help,

Ahmed.

Comment: You seem to be very confused about the HTTP execution model.

Comment: I observe that with a lot of coders who start using frameworks and languages that hide the underlaying mechanics, instead of sockets, http, html, javascript - and only then serverside languages. Every course should start with students telnetting to a webserver, imho ;)

Comment: Hi Konerak, the problem is always deadline. "They" always ask for tasks in very short period and leave no place for deep understanding. And when you find time , a pradigm shift changes the rules , and we have to start all over again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly interact with the client's filesystem.
Period.

Instead, you should create an ASHX handler that sends the PDF to the client, then point the `src` to that ASHX.
You can pass information to the ASHX handler using the querystring.

Comment: Thanks SLaks for your help. I think that's what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem :

```
iframePDF1.Attributes.Add("src", "ShowPDF.ashx?pID=" & Request.QueryString("pID"))
```

Comment: hi, can you maybe explain a bit more? Say my local path is C:\Document\temp.pdf, how would I actually do it?