# Displaying a pdf to webpage using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating a pdf using iTextSharp. I would like to display it on the webpage and let the user save it from the online pdf viewer. *dynamicpdf* has a drawtoweb() method, but it is not free to use and I cannot find the same functionality using iTextSharp. How can I display the pdf?

```
string newFile = "Pdf Document.pdf";
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
        doc.AddCreator("Myself");
        doc.AddTitle("Sample PDF Document");
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello, World!"));
        doc.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just display the PDF like any other website does? Just send the generated file to the user as a response stream with the correct meta data. It will open automatically in its default PDF viewer, most likely inside the browser.
As far as I understand the [DrawToWeb method of dynamicpdf](http://www.cete.com/Support/NET_Help_Library_09_04/ceTe.DynamicPDF~ceTe.DynamicPDF.Document~DrawToWeb%28String%29.html) that's exactly what it is doing.

**UPDATE:**
Some research brought up a solution like this:
Add an iframe to your web page:

```
<IFrame runat="server" id="iframepdf">
</IFrame>
```

and populate it with the PDF file:

```
iframepdf.Attributes.Add("src", "showpdf.ashx?pdf=" + xyz);
```

See [How <iframe src can read local temp file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535766/how-iframe-src-can-read-local-temp-file) for more info.

Comment: Perhaps. How would I go about doing that? I'm looking at Response.TransmitFile, but it wont accept Response.TransmitFile(doc); or Response.TransmitFile("Pdf Document.pdf");

Comment: Thanks, but im getting a resource cannot be found error in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just buying a license to *dynamicpdf*. It was much easier to work with than itextsharp.